# How to configure with java @Configuration Spring to run jersey in filter mode

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jersey

Hi I have entry in application.properties:

```
spring.jersey.type=filter
```

that allows me to run jersey with spring in filter mode, and thanks to that I can share API Resources and static content, like home page or swagger docs.

I know that for this service I will always run this jersey that way. So it will never change. I would like to configure it using java like f.e.: here:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        // scan the resources package for our resources
        packages(getClass().getPackage().getName() + ".resources");
        property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to express using java code this property entry: `spring.jersey.type=filter`? I would like to keep application.properties only for real environment base configuration. Jersey filter mode will never be changed.

`spring.jersey.type=filter` is spring configuration, not jersey

I've checked those docks: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html about registering Using filter, but fail on this.

Comment: Do it and see @masterdany88 :)

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Your `JerseyConfig` class can be used the same whether you are using `type=servlet` (the default) or `type=filter`. There doesn't need to be any change to it.

Comment: I wonna express this: `spring.jersey.type=filter` using java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `application.properties` that you already have is the way to go here IMO, this is a "straightforward" spring-boot way of doing configuration.

You can place this file into `src/main/resources` or `src/main/resources/config` (in case you run it externally and it will pick it.

Now if you really want to do it in java, here are a couple of ways:

**Option 1:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp{

public static void main(String[] args){
    SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MyApp.class);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("spring.jersey.type", "filter");
    application.setDefaultProperties(properties);

    application.run(args);
  }
}
```

**Option 2**

Create `org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor` and register it in `META-INF/spring.factories`:
The interface of this environment post-processor allows adding properties.

An example of such a post-processor can be found [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-environmentpostprocessor)

**Option 3**

By convention decide that all your services will run "jersey" profile in addition to the regular profile (dev, prod, or whatever you have there)

Then you can create `application-jersey.properties` and it will be picked by spring boot application automatically as long as you specify jersey profile (`--spring.profiles.active=dev,jersey`) or programmatically

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApp.class);
   app.setAdditionalProfiles("jersey"); 
   app.run(args);
 }
}
```

Comment: Is this first option will override every entry in application.properties? Or just one declared in java?

Comment: Ok, I've checked. It only override one in java

Comment: From the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html Set default environment properties which will be used in addition to those in the existing Environment.